# How to plot a 3D graph with Z axis being the magnitude of values in a csv?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib, 3d

I believe the X and Y values in the plot should be represented by the columns and lines in the csv, which looks like this:

```
0,original,1.0000,0.9999,0.9998,0.9997,0.9996,0.9995... 0.9900
1,28663,   4144,6096,6859,7366,7876,8125...
2,11268,   1374,2119,2393,2615,2809,2904...
3,14734,   2122,3115,3466,3740,4011,4144...
4,13341,   1452,2322,2689,2877,3114,3238...
5,18458,   2677,3643,4047,4333,4652,4806...
6,13732,   1621,2224,2502,2704,2930,3020...
7,17771,   2955,3904,4270,4566,4872,5041...
8,14447,   1822,2437,2715,2933,3179,3292...
.
.
.
5400,18458,2677,3643,4047,4333,4652,4806
```

I would like to plot my data in a graphic. If I do so in a 2D graphic it looks really ugly.

Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0zLL.png) shows this data in a 2D format, each column series is a different color, the "original" values are the blue series for example. It looks to me that it would have a better visual representation if it was 3D.
[image]

I would be looking for something like image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ty38.png). **I understand that the Z values are the magnitude of each cell in the table**. I believe I would have to plot a bunch of different series (where each series comes from each whole column on the csv). Am I right?

[image]

That being said, my question is: **How can I plot my '.csv' data in a 3D graphic, considering the situation I pointed out?**

**EDIT:** I found a code that kinda does what I want. I got it from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1328448/3d-plot-with-matplotlib-from-imported-data). I guess I would like to apply each column like *np.meshgrid(DataAll1D[:,0]* adds column 0 to the plot. It seems like the meshgrid function accepts any number of 1D arrays I just don't know how to do that in python.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

DataAll1D = np.loadtxt("datacsv_1d.csv", delimiter=",")
# create 2d x,y grid (both X and Y will be 2d)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(DataAll1D[:,0], DataAll1D[:,1])

# repeat Z to make it a 2d grid
Z = np.tile(DataAll1D[:,2], (len(DataAll1D[:,2]), 1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='ocean')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what the best way to plot it is, but a 3D surface can be just as well (maybe better) visualized as a raster using `plt.imshow()`. You can pass a 2D array to this function. What is the purpose of the plot? I mean, what kind of things are you looking for in the data?

Comment: The values here are not random, they come from my master's project. This numbers are nodes being removed from a graph. The labels in the 1st line are the probabilities in which the nodes have to be removed and the labels in the 1st column show the depths of such nodes. The higher the probability, more nodes are removed (and values are shown considering their depth). So there should be a growth going on there and I would like to see a mountain shape like when plotting this values in 3d.

Comment: The last line is not the real one in case you noticed its values are not greater than previous lines and you think I'm lying hahaha.

Comment: Can you not take the row number as the z-axis value?

Comment: @PGHE after you asked I realized that the Z values should be the magnitude of the cells in the table. I edited my question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very minimal example, but I guess what you want to achieve is have each of your curves separated from the others in a 3D space. The code below generates two plots, one that draws curves individually, the other which treats the input as a surface. You can easily build onto this and achieve a more specific goal of yours I guess.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

data = numpy.array([[28663, 4144, 6096, 6859, 7366, 7876, 8125],
                    [11268, 1374, 2119, 2393, 2615, 2809, 2904],
                    [14734, 2122, 3115, 3466, 3740, 4011, 4144],
                    [13341, 1452, 2322, 2689, 2877, 3114, 3238],
                    [18458, 2677, 3643, 4047, 4333, 4652, 4806],
                    [13732, 1621, 2224, 2502, 2704, 2930, 3020]])
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, num=0, figsize=(16, 8),
                             subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    ax.plot3D(numpy.repeat(i, data.shape[0]), numpy.arange(data.shape[0]),
              data[:, i])
gridY, gridX = numpy.mgrid[1:data.shape[0]:data.shape[0] * 1j,
                           1:data.shape[1]:data.shape[1] * 1j]
pSurf = bx.plot_surface(gridX, gridY, data, cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(pSurf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick!! I just had to add so that the data comes from the csv: **data = genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',')**